# Passing a predefined filename argument to awk via system() in R

Tags: r, bash, path, awk

I am struggling with something small but important with syntax, trying to pass a pre-defined path and filename to awk within the system() call in R (OSX, R3.0.1; readLines() and scan() can NOT accomplish what I need).

The use of system and the file name, directly within R, works fine

```
system("awk 'NR==2' ~/path/filename", intern=TRUE)
```

However

```
filename<-"~/path/filename"
system("awk 'NR==2' filename", intern=TRUE)
```

returns the frustrating error

```
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
Warning message:
running command 'awk 'NR==2' filename' had status 2 
awk: can't open file filename
source line number 1
```

I expect I need to escape something somewhere in the filename, but I don't know where, or how.

Comment: no idea how does R code look like, but I guess the problem is you wrote the `filename` variable in literal string.  you could try if this works in your R: `system(paste("awk 'NR==2' ", filename), intern=TRUE)`

Comment: This did it.  Interesting.  Note to @konsolebox, works with the absolute or relative path, but absolute on its own did not alter outcome.

Comment: ok, then I posted it as answer.

Comment: Think of what you pass to system as exactly what you would put in the command line.  You need to use `paste` to actually construct the command you would write on the command line.  This is a good thing - otherwise doing something like `system("chmod +x file")` might replace the `x` in there with whatever is stored in `x`.  That would be horribly unpredictable and would make for some frustrating times...

Comment: Come on @beckerhoppper. Give Kent the checkmark.

Comment: @DWin Kent first wrote the answer in the comments.  I went to bed.  I was waiting for him to post it as an answer.  Tranquilo mi amigo.

Comment: @Dason very clear points overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my first line of R code. :)

I guess the problem is you wrote the filename variable in literal string. You should first build the awk command with string concatenation, and then pass it to `system()`, like:

```
system(paste("awk 'NR==2' ", filename), intern=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `~/path/filename` with its absolute form instead. e.g. `/home/user/path/filename`.